# Error not occurs when checking for reachability to 0.0.0.0 in Local Mac-based IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 Network

Tags: ios, ipv6

Follow this paper : [your_app_and_next_generation_networks](http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/719ui2k57m/719/719_your_app_and_next_generation_networks.pdf), at **What Break** segment, when checking for reachability to 0.0.0.0 in Local Mac-based IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 Network then error will occurs (  You're Not Connected to the Internet)

However, after created Local Mac-based IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 Network,and I try to checking for reachability to 0.0.0.0 by following code :

`Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
[reachability startNotifier];`

then no error is shown for me!

here is implement of `reachabilityForInternetConnection` method from [Reachability Github](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability)

```
+(instancetype)reachabilityForInternetConnection {
  struct sockaddr_in zeroAddress;
  bzero(&zeroAddress, sizeof(zeroAddress));
  zeroAddress.sin_len = sizeof(zeroAddress);
  zeroAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;

  return [self reachabilityWithAddress:&zeroAddress];
}

+(instancetype)reachabilityWithAddress:(void *)hostAddress {
   SCNetworkReachabilityRef ref = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(kCFAllocatorDefault, (const struct sockaddr*)hostAddress);

   if (ref) 
    {
     id reachability = [[self alloc] initWithReachabilityRef:ref];
     return reachability;
    }

   return nil;
}
```

Comment: Even if you get lucky in your own test environment, Apple explicitly says you shouldn't rely on that, so don't.

Comment: @SanderSteffann thanks to your comment! But in my case, I want a error, but any not show!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the following code ,　It don't work if we use valid global ip.

```
struct sockaddr_in addr;
addr.sin_len = INET_ADDRSTRLEN;
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"); // valid global ip instead of 0.0.0.0
Reachability* reachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithAddress:&addr];
[reachability startNotifier];
NSLog(@"reachable[%d]", reachability.currentReachabilityStatus); // when ipv6, it isNotReachable and when ipv4, it is ReachableViaWiFi
```

Comment: I was referring to the following url . http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/24771/mac%E3%81%A7ipv6%E7%92%B0%E5%A2%83%E3%82%92%E4%BD%9C%E6%88%90%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6-ios%E3%81%A7sockaddr-in%E3%82%92%E5%88%A9%E7%94%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%82%82%E5%8B%95%E4%BD%9C%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%86